# IdentityServer 4 custom Introspection response

Tags: identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer 4 and I want to customize the Introspection response to include the user's claims whenever the user send it's reference token for validation. I couldn't find any documentation about customizing the Introspection response. Is it possible? Is there a better way for the user to get it's claims?

Thanks!